# Route Hijacking Override

Tags: c#-4.0, umbraco, umbraco7

In Umbraco 7 I am dealing with a package that route hijacks a document type with a controller with the same name as the document type (default hijacking pattern).  I would like to hijack the hijacker.

Anyone know if this is possible in the umbraco api?

Answer (score 0):

Hijacking the route means "implementing a controller" for a specific documenttype.  Can you elaborate a littlebit on why or what you exactly want to do?

Comment: There is a controller already written for a document type from a package we are using (Articulate) which is a blog package.  I want to override it by inheriting the articulate controller and have my controller handle the route hijack instead of Articulates.  However I don't think this is possible.

Comment: Basically I want to override Articulates handling of the ArticulateRichText document type so we can add some custom filtering for date ranges and other criteria to blog rollups.  However I'm thinking what I will need to do is make a new document type that inherits the rich text one then create my own controller to hijack it and inherit the Articulate Controller.